# Reset Asus rt-n66u Black Knight Wireless Router

Tags: download, connection, internet-connection

I am having trouble downloading most files.

How can I reset my [Asus rt-n66u Black Knight Wireless Router](http://www.asus.com/Networking/RTN66U/) to factory settings?

Comment: So this happens with any download? Did you try other clients, like `wget` maybe?

Comment: More info about your connection. Single computer X Network; Direct connection X router; Cable X Wifi; Chrome X other programs; Proxy X non-proxy; only from yours computer X other too... etc. :)

Comment: You may try flashing new firmware for your device from http://www.asus.com/support/.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a reset button between the Two USB sockets, and Gigabit Ethernet WAN port.

Press and hold the reset button for 5 seconds to restore factory defaults.

Comment: I had to ensure the router booted a little bit .. if I tried to press the reset button either while turning on the router (as is quite common on other routers) or immediately after start, I couldn't get it to factory reset. I had to wait 20-30 seconds and then press reset button for 5 seconds until lamps start blinking